# How to make dual release in google play market then sign key have been changed?

Tags: google-play, bundle, digital-signature, release, playback

How to make dual release in google play market then sign key have been changed?

I have an old APK and new bundle with new key.

old uploading was made via CI/CD gradle publishReleaseApk

[image]